# Evenly Assign Tasks to Employees Based on Time Per Task

Tags: excel, google-sheets

This is my first post on here so let me know how to improve!

I've been collecting data recently on time to assemble products at work within a Google Sheet. From this, I've found the average time per step in the assembly process and have found that the tasks are not evenly distributed(ie. person 1 has 2 tasks that take 8hrs total, while person 2 has 10 tasks that take 5 hours total).

I've been combing through the internet trying to find a way that I can assign these assembly steps to each employee so that each employee roughly has the same total time of assembly(ie. all employees have tasks that have a total of 7hrs+/- for completion).

I want to do all of this within Google Sheets or Excel, but am running out of ideas on how to make it work.

Anyone have an idea on how to get this to work? Or any ideas what program to use to make this work?

Let me know if I can provide any more information. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like the knapsack problem

Comment: @player0 here is a link to a test sheet I've made.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aoGECbE94wa7jT0mjzWgQKaCVEp5TooZpnXA9wZ4ZTM/edit?usp=sharing